# How to solve a Venn diagram of 3 sets where a certain value is not given?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a math task where I must find out how many people are **only part of club A**, and because how many people are in club A at the start isn't specified I am struggling with the problem.
The current information I have is:

1. There are 39 people in total.
2. 22 people are part of club B.
3. 27 people are part of club C.
4. 12 people are part of club B and C.
5. 8 people are part of club A and B.
6. 10 people are part of club A and C.
7. 3 people are part of clubs A, B and C.
8. Nobody is not part of any club.

So far I have created this simple Venn diagram but have had no luck in going further:
[image: Current visualization]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the fact that there are 39 people total, and that every person is in at least one club.

This means that if you add up the numbers in your Venn Diagram, you should get 39. Can you solve the rest of the problem from here?